# Multiple problems working with Telerik's RadEditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, telerik

**Below is the link to the code that has the two RAdEditors I am using on my page:**

http://pastebin.com/GsgKhL76

**The problems that I am facing are as follows:**

1. When I click inside of EditorQues, its toolbar shows. But when I click to type inside EditorAns, EditorQues's basic toolbar keeps on showing.
   I want this basic toolbar to hide when focus is inside EditorAns.
2. Ajax Spell Check is not working in both the Editors. However, when I embed the same Editors in an aspx page that has no master page, the Ajax Spell Checker works great.
   Why is Spell checker not working in this page of mine that has a master page? When I click  on Spell check button in both  Editors' toolbar, it displays message "Spell check in progress" and both "Finish Spell Check"
   and "Cancel" Buttons are greyed out so I am unable click them and I have to refresh the page everytime to make those "Finish Spell Check"
   and "Cancel" Buttons to go away. How do I fix this? I mean what has using master page got to do with the Spell checker? I tested with this another master page, Spell checker works fine I that.
   Why is it not working with a particular master page? What could be wrong?
3. In the Editor. CustomSkin. Css, I have set the default font as 14px, Verdana and Normal but when the Editor loads, I do not see font properties
   That I have set in this css. Why are the properties not getting overridden and the master page's css is being applied?
4. Required field validator is not working  with rad editor. Editor's content gets stored as either and Empty string or a break tab "br/".
   How do I validate RadEditor so empty string doesn't get stored in my DB?

**Below are the css files:**

**Master Page's CSS file:**

```
body {padding:0; margin:0; background-image:url(../images/bg.gif); background-repeat:repeat-x repeat-y;}
body, td, input, textarea{
    font-size:11px;
        font-family:Tahoma;
    color:#5D5F60;
    line-height:13px;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0px;

}
```

**Editor. CustomSkin. Css**
I followed some tutorial on Telerik's website on how to use external CSS and implemented as follows: -

I have renamed Default Skin's CSS file (Editor. Default. Css) to Editor. CustomSkin. Css and made the following additions: -

**Added this in my custom skin:**

```
body
{
    font-family:Verdana!important;  /*Why is Verdana not being set as default font in the editor even though I have set important here? */
    font-style:normal!important;
    font-size:14px!important;   /*Here too font size is not being set as 14 px and text appears smaller than 14 px */
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5
{
    color:Black!important;
    background-color:Transparent;
    background-image:none!important;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom:0px!important;
    font-family:Segoe UI,Arial,Sans-serif;
    cursor:default;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    font: "Segoe UI",Arial,Sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

h1{ font-size: 2em !important;}
h2{ font-size: 1.5em !important;}
h3{ font-size: 1.17em !important;}
h4{ font-size: 1em !important;}
h5{ font-size: .83em !important;}
h6{ font-size: .75em !important;}
```

**Another change I made is:**

```
.CustomSkin.RadEditor .reContentCell
{
    background-image:none !important;
    background-color:White !important;
    border: solid 1px #828282;

}
```

I have set the content area's background of editors as white, else it was picking up master page's background image

I followed [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editorastextbox/defaultcs.aspx) example to make the editor look like a textbox

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editorastextbox/defaultcs.aspx

Its working fine but I still see grey shadow around EditorQues which is RadEditor as a textbox on my page. How do I get rid of that?

Also in the head section of my page as you can see above, I have commented out the following: -

```
<%--<link href="http://www.example.com/Skins/CustomSkin/EditorAsTextBox.CustomSkin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
--%>
```

(Edit note: example.com was mysite.com before edit. [Info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke))

I had to do this because if I add reference to EditorAsTextBox. CustomSkin. Css in th ehead section, the EditorAns's toolbar's background color(grey) vanishes
And becomes white. I have no clue how to fix this either.

Sorry for so many questions. Hoping I'll get help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this here since I can't comment yet due to lower reputation. This would definitely be something to submit in a support ticket for Telerik. Keep in mind that the forums are not a support ticket, they are simply a community forum for the Telerik community while a support ticket can be submitted by logging into your account and clicking on the "Get Support" link.

The reason for this is that overall your code looks fine, but submitting an entire sample to the Telerik team themselves would be a great idea here since they can debug it locally. In the meantime I recommend reading over their [online documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editoroverview.html) and look through their [online demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) to see if there is something that might be missing in your application.